# Pandas - create new column based on conditional value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I would like to create a new column `df['indexed']` based on the value of the previous row of the column `df['col2']`. Except, if in row of column `df['col2']` is not `"x"` (in this example a string - date), I would like the set `100` in `df['indexed']`. So I expect a column `"indexed"` that begins every time at a value of `100`, if `df['col2']` is not a `"x"`.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [0.02,0.12,-0.1,0-0.07,0.01,0.02,0.12,-0.1,0-0.07,0.01],
     'col2': ['x','x','x','2021-60-30','x','x','x','x','x','x']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['col1'] = df['col1']+1
df['indexed'] = 0
df['indexed'].iloc[0] = 100 #to set a start

#what i tried:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['col2'] == 'x':
        df['indexed']= df['col1'] * df['indexed'].shift(1)
    else:
        df['indexed']= 100
```

I expect:

[image]

Comment: Please show expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `where`:

```
df['indexed'] = (df['col1'] * df['col1'].shift(1)).where(df['col2']=='x', 100)
df
```

Output:

```
   col1        col2   indexed
0  1.02           x       NaN
1  1.12           x    1.1424
2  0.90           x    1.0080
3  0.93  2021-60-30  100.0000
4  1.01           x    0.9393
5  1.02           x    1.0302
6  1.12           x    1.1424
7  0.90           x    1.0080
8  0.93           x    0.8370
9  1.01           x    0.9393
```

**Update** If you want to calculate cumulative product starting from each non-`x` value in `col2`:

```
g = df.groupby(df['col2'].ne('x').cumsum())['col1']
df['indexed'] = g.cumprod() / g.transform('first') * 100
```

Output:

```
   col1        col2     indexed
0  1.02           x  100.000000
1  1.12           x  112.000000
2  0.90           x  100.800000
3  0.93  2021-60-30  100.000000
4  1.01           x  101.000000
5  1.02           x  103.020000
6  1.12           x  115.382400
7  0.90           x  103.844160
8  0.93           x   96.575069
9  1.01           x   97.540819
```

Comment: thank you. Based on your solution I found out that I made a logical mistake. here: df['indexed']= df['col1'] * df['indexed'].shift(1).  sorry

Comment: @Alex Please see the update, hope I got right what you wanted to achieve

Comment: i do not understand the logic behind your solution. can you tell me, how I have to change the code if I would to set the "row-value" of "col1" instead of 100?!

Comment: @Alex The logic is that we make groups with each group starting with non-`x` value in `col2`, then calculate cumulative product of `col1` and rescale to make the first value in the group to be 100. If you want the first value to be that of `col1`, just use `df['indexed'] = g.cumprod()` instead of `df['indexed'] = g.cumprod() / g.transform('first') * 100`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the apply method and just using your own function:

```
def my_funct(row)

    if row['col2'] == 'x':
       row['indexed']= row['col1'] * row['col1'].shift(1)
    else:
       row['indexed']= 100
```

And then:

```
df= df.apply(my_funct, axis=1)
```